# Flyway ExceptionInInitializerError when trying to run migrations

Tags: java, flyway

Every time I try to run migrations, I get these massive exceptions and have been unsuccessful in finding the cause. I am using it as a part of an application that is an add-on to another application. When I tried to run it my itself it worked fine. However I need it to work in the add-on environment and don't understand why it wouldn't as I have never run into a similar problem with any other external libraries I have used with the add-on. I have checked to confirm that Flyway and all of those classes are available on the class path, they are.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector.isSlf4jAvailable(FeatureDetector.java:96) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.LogCreatorFactory.getLogCreator(LogCreatorFactory.java:39) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.api.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:78) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector.<clinit>(FeatureDetector.java:25) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.LogCreatorFactory.getLogCreator(LogCreatorFactory.java:35) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.api.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:78) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.<clinit>(Flyway.java:86) ~[?:?]
at me.calebbassham.stats.Stats.setupDatabase(Stats.java:22) ~[?:?]
at com.oblivionuhc.uhc.UHC$onEnable$3.run(UHC.kt:104) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:82) ~[patched_1.13.2.jar:git-Paper-486]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:52) ~[patched_1.13.2.jar:git-Paper-486]
at com.destroystokyo.paper.ServerSchedulerReportingWrapper.run(ServerSchedulerReportingWrapper.java:22) ~[patched_1.13.2.jar:git-Paper-486]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate class org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogCreator : org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogCreator
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.instantiate(ClassUtils.java:63) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.LogCreatorFactory.getLogCreator(LogCreatorFactory.java:40) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.api.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:78) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.<clinit>(ClassUtils.java:39) ~[?:?]
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogCreator
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.instantiate(ClassUtils.java:61) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.LogCreatorFactory.getLogCreator(LogCreatorFactory.java:40) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.api.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:78) ~[?:?]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.<clinit>(ClassUtils.java:39) ~[?:?]
... 15 more
```

Comment: Providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. I also suggest looking for slf4j related issues on Flyway Github (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1922) looks similar to yours). Maybe you'll find some solutions there.

Comment: @CalebBassham Have You solve this problem? I've the same issue.

Comment: No I was never able to find a solution to this. Ended up just using their command line tool but it would have been preferable to be able to use the API.